# How would you mimic the glaze of a donut (varying opacity) in vector art?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

I've made a vector graphic of a donut. See [image: here]. But I'd like to add an effect of a glaze where the glaze has differing opacity throughout. How can I achieve this?!

Comment: I've taken my vector art into Photohop and gone over the glaze with white brush with the hardness at 0% and opacity way down and it's getting the effect I'm after!

Answer (score 5):

You could use a **Gradient Mesh**.

With Illustrator CS5 or newer you can apply transparency to gradient mesh points. Then you would need a clipping mask to remove the "glaze" from over the hole in the donut.

Gradient Mesh:
[image: Donut]

I've used a gradient mesh for the basic shape and transparency of the glaze. Then I added a clipping mask to the mesh to remove the "hole" of the donut. I then added some simple arched shapes with a black to white gradient fill applied tot hem, changed the blend mode to "screen" (only works in RGB mode) and placed them around the glaze edge to add a bit more depth.

Sprinkles are just for fun (they are symbols).

Comment: These donuts are making me thirsty!